# How to load program reading stdin and taking parameters in gdb?

Tags: redirect, emacs, gdb, command-line-arguments

Question cribbed from [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071102162016AASqPeB):

> I have a program that takes input from
> stdin and also takes some parameters
> from command line. It looks like this:
>
> ```
> cat input.txt > myprogram -path "/home/user/work"
> ```
>
> I try to debug the code with gdb
> inside emacs, by M-x gdb, I try to
> load the program with the command:
>
> ```
> gdb cat input.txt > myprogram -path "/home/user/work"
> ```
>
> However, gdb does not like it.

Unfortunately I don't understand the solution and am not sure what to do beyond compiling with the `-g` option and running the command M-x gdb.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you were doing it from a shell you'd do it like this:

```
% gdb myprogram
gdb> run params ... < input.txt
```

This seems to work within emacs too.

Comment: The redirection seems to work but I get some errors.
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Program exited with code 042.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's likely a general GDB error, and probably nothing to do with the fact you're running within emacs.  Learn how to run GDB from a shell first (with a new question if necessary), and then worry about running it inside emacs.

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason I typed void main(int argc, char *argv[]) instead of "int main..." and it slipped my eye. Anyways everything works fine now; thanks for your help!

Comment: A belated thank you - the gdb manual is a pain in the butt to dredge through.

Comment: On Windows using msys64 I get `<` and `input.txt` as `argv` arguments to my program :( I'll keep digging around these answers with my gdb 8.2.1 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544325/input-redirection-in-gdb-mingw

Comment: It's not working. I invoked GDB with `gdb a.out` and run by `r arg1 < input.txt`, but it recognized `arg1`, `<` and `input.txt` as three arguments. **It turns out that `set startup-with-shell off` is the culprit!**

Answer (score 36):

There are several ways to do it:

```
$ gdb myprogram
(gdb) r -path /home/user/work < input.txt
```

or

```
$ gdb myprogram
(gdb) set args -path /home/user/work < input.txt
(gdb) r
```

or

```
$ gdb -ex 'set args -path /home/user/work < input.txt' myprogram
(gdb) r
```

where the gdb `run` command (`r`) uses by default the arguments as set previously with `set args`.

Comment: When I try this with gdb in cygwin, it doesn't work. The "show args" command shows that I entered the args I wanted, but when I start the program with "r", the program waits until I type stuff instead of reading from the specified file.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman, well, I can't test it with Cygwin - perhaps their gdb version is somehow limited

Comment: Why not simply `gdb -ex 'r -path /home/user/work < input.txt' myprogram` in the third variant?

Comment: @Ruslan, works as well - using 'set args ...' just gives you the chance to interactively define some break points etc. before running the program

Comment: True, but you can also set the breakpoint non-interactively, e.g. `gdb -ex 'b main' -ex 'r -path /home/user/work < input.txt' myprogram`.

Comment: @Ruslan, sure, nobody implied that you cannot do that. Sometimes you want to do it interactively. Sometimes you don't. I think the answer contains enough examples such that this is all pretty obvious.

Answer (score 7):

This is eleven years later, and this question has an answer already, but for someone just like me in the future, I just wanted to add some thing.

After you run `gdb your_program`, if you just type `run < file_containing_input`, the program will just run till the end, and you might not catch the problem, so before you do `run < file_containing_input` do a break. Something like this

```
$ gdb your_program
gdb> break main
gdb> run < file_containing_input
```

Answer (score 6):

For completeness' sake upon starting a debugging session there is also the --args option. ie)

```
gdb gdbarg1 gdbarg2 --args yourprog arg1 arg2 -x arg3
```

Comment: How would you redirect input.txt as an input to yourprog upon starting a debugging session like this?

Comment: @Peter: `gdb --args yourprog.out input.txt`

Comment: That only works if "yourprog" expects a file name to specify the input, not input redirection.

Answer (score 1):

And if you do not need to debug from the very beginning you can also attach to an already running process by using:

```
$ gdb myprogram xxx
```

where xxx is the process id. Then you do not need to tell gdb the starting arguments.

Comment: You missed to answer to the question title, at the part "reading stdin". I would make a good comment somewhere if it were shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point to the technique with mkfifo as described here:

[gdb - debugging with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456253/gdb-debugging-with-pipe)

if you have a more complicated pipe than reading from just one file, such as:

```
cat jonesforth.f examples/defining-words.f - |./jonesforth
```

the mkfifo can be very convenient.