# gdb won't accept stdin redirection in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb, cygwin, stdin

I'm trying to debug a program using gdb mode in emacs. It was compiled with g++, and I'm using cygwin. My program takes one command line argument, and also takes input from stdin, which I redirect from a file, like this:

```
program.exe inputFile.dat <otherInput.dat
```

The problem is, gdb is sending the string

```
"<otherInput.dat"
```

as a command line argument instead of redirecting stdin. How do I force gdb to redirect stdin?

EDIT:

Within gdb, I'm using the command:

```
run inputFile.dat <otherInput.dat
```

It doesn't work when I use gdb outside of emacs, either.

EDIT #2:

dfa pointed out a similar question: [How to load program reading stdin and taking parameters in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer for that question isn't working for me... Could it be a cygwin-related bug?

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb) ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have to use the `run` command:

> You can redirect your program's input and/or output using shell redirection with the run > command. For example,
>
> ```
> run > outfile
> ```

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_5.html#SEC24

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but it doesn't redirect.

Comment: This is why: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1998-11/msg00978.html 1988 and still not fixed, I guess

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash, you can attach gdb to the process immediately by doing `PROGRAM ARGS < FILE & jobs -x gdb PROGRAM %1`. Depending on the shell you use, you may find yourself having to use more creative methods (probably involving output from `ps -C` being redirected into gdb's command line).