# gdb - debugging with pipe

Tags: c, gdb

Say I have a two programs named **blah** and **ret**. I want to debug **blah** program which receives input from **ret** program via I/O redirection. How do I debug the **blah** program in the following case using gdb?

```
bash> ret | blah
```

Comment: Is this different than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521015/how-to-pass-arguments-and-redirect-stdin-from-a-file-to-program-run-in-gdb

Answer (score 51, accepted):

At first, you may run the program and debug it by pid.  This solution, of course, doesn't cover all cases.

Another approach is to use Linux capabilities for inter-process communication.  In short, you redirect the output of `ret` to a FIFO special file ("named pipe") and then read from that FIFO via debugger.  Here's how it's done.  From bash, run:

```
mkfifo foo
```

This creates a special file in your directory that will serve as a *named pipe*.  When you write text to this file (using the same syntax `echo "Hello" >foo`), the writing program will block until someone reads the data from the file (`cat <foo`, for instance).  In our case, a gdb-controlled process will read from this file.

After you created a fifo, run from bash:

```
ret > foo &   # ampersand because it may block as nobody is reading from foo
gdb blah
```

Then, in gdb prompt, run

```
run <foo
```

And get the desired effect.  Note that you can't read the data from the fifo (as well as from a usual pipe) twice: when you've read all the data, the `blah` process dies and you should repeat the command writing to foo (you may do it from the other shell window).

When you're done, remove the fifo with  `rm foo` (or place it into the directory where it will automatically be removed upon system restart, such as `/tmp`).

Comment: If you can afford the disk space you could also just pipe it into a regular file `foo`, instead of a FIFO `foo` (saves you one command :).

Comment: Regular files and FIFOs/pipes have different semantics for read(). If you reach EOF in a regular file, read() returns with maybe less bytes read than specified. If you read from a FIFO/pipe, read() blocks until the specified number of bytes arrives, or the process writing to the pipe has exited.

Answer (score 19):

GDB's `run` command uses `bash` to perform redirection. A simple way to achieve the equivalent of `ret | blah` is to use bash's [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) feature.

```
$ gdb blah
...
(gdb) run < <(ret)
```

---

Explanation: bash substitutes `<(ret)` with something like `/dev/fd/123`, which is a file descriptor of the stdout of `ret`. We can use that fd similarly to a named FIFO as described in the other answer, except that we don't have to manually create it ourselves, nor worry about the lifetime of the `ret` process.