# wildfly-swarm launch from Eclipse "org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

For multiple projects, I use wildfly-swarm to avoid installing a webserver. The swarm jar file is generated and I can successfully launch it through "java -jar mypackage-swarm.jar".

However, to debug it easily, I would like to launch it via my IDE (eclipse). Either by directly launching my main class or using fakerplace, I have the following exception :

```
Fakereplace is running.
Dependencies not bundled, will resolve from local M2REPO
2017-01-17 08:31:41,806 org.wildfly.swarm.internal.SwarmMessages  [main] DEBUG Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
2017-01-17 08:31:41,811 org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm  [main] DEBUG WFSWARM0020: Stage Config found in swarm.project.stage.file system property at location: null
2017-01-17 08:31:41,862 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0018: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2016.12.1
2017-01-17 08:31:41,865 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0018: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2016.12.1
2017-01-17 08:31:41,865 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0018: Installed fraction:            Spring WebMVC - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:spring:2016.12.1
org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/apache/xerces/main/module.xml
...
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to resolve artifact 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0.SP5' (position: END_TAG seen ...<resources>\n    <artifact name="xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0.SP5"/>... @5:52)
```

I've found similar exceptions on internet, but I cannot find a solution.

Has anyone any idea on this ?

Comment: Have tried https://github.com/fbricon/wildfly-hive

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run it as jar application ?
I'm not sure how to do that in eclipse below is example in intellj but for eclipse you can find your solution here:

[eclipse: how to debug a Java program as a .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732259/eclipse-how-to-debug-a-java-program-as-a-jar-file)

[image]

Comment: I did, but It ends up with the same exception. probably a dependencies conflict