# How do I run a program with commandline arguments using GDB within a Bash script?

Tags: gdb, command-line-arguments

When running a program on GDB, usually, the arguments for the program are given at the `run` command. Is there a way to run the program using GDB and as well as give arguments within a shell script?

I saw an answer in a related question, mentioning that we can attach GDB to the program after the script starts executing. But then I will have to 'wait' the program.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments and redirect stdin from a file to program run in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521015/how-to-pass-arguments-and-redirect-stdin-from-a-file-to-program-run-in-gdb)

Answer (score 964, accepted):

You can run gdb with `--args` parameter:

```
gdb --args executablename arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If you are doing this often (e.g. when running GDB from a script), you might want to consider the following arguments to automate things further. First, you can place your GDB commands (such as 'run') in a text file and provide the filename to the `-x` argument. Second, you can have GDB exit after running your commands by providing the `--batch` argument. A full example:

```
gdb -x commands.txt --batch --args executablename arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Argg, `man gdb` does not contain `--args`, that's why I did not find it. `gdb --help` does.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 GDB is GNU.  To view the full documentation of GNU tools, remember to use `info gdb` next time :-).

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 I got hooked to info after discovering the 'i' key (`index-search`). Try: `info gdb`, then 'i', then '--args'. It'll bring you right to it.

Comment: @Apteryx When I press 'i' it shows "No indices found." at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @WawrzyniecPruski on which GNU/Linux distribution is that?  I suspect something's wrong with the info manual shipped with their GDB package; using GNU Guix, you can `guix shell gdb info-reader -- info gdb`, and the `i RET --args`  sequence works from there.

Comment: @Apteryx Centos 7.9.2009

Answer (score 228):

```
gdb -ex=r --args myprogram arg1 arg2
```

`-ex=r` is short for `-ex=run` and tells gdb to run your program immediately, rather than wait for you to type "run" at the prompt. Then `--args` says that everything that follows is the command and arguments, just as you'd normally type them at the commandline prompt.

Comment: Didn't know about the `-exe=r` very useful!

Comment: I see, you can't do `gdb --args -ex=r myprogram arg1 arg2`.

Answer (score 93):

Another way to do this, which I personally find slightly more convenient and intuitive (without having to remember the `--args` parameter), is to compile normally, and use `r arg1 arg2 arg3` directly from within `gdb`, like so:

```
$ gcc -g *.c *.h
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is hoping to avoid having to do.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, thank you, fair point. I'm not sure how that's escaped my notice for so long. I think I'll leave the answer here, however, because iirc, I stumbled upon this question when I'd googled something like "How to pass command line arguments using gdb", and finding the answer missing, I went on to add it, without realizing (for almost a year!) that my answer didn't address the question at hand.

Comment: @KarateSnowMachine As someone arriving from Google as well, this answer is *more* along the lines of what I was looking for. Perhaps we should revise the question to be more general since it has such a general title, or maybe we should narrow the title. Making it less restrictive would probably be more useful to the greater number of readers.

Answer (score 21):

You could create a file with context:

```
run arg1 arg2 arg3 etc

program input
```

And call gdb like

```
gdb prog < file
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer of Hugo Ideler.
When using arguments having themself prefix like `--` or `-`, I was not sure to conflict with gdb one.

It seems gdb takes all after `args` option as arguments for the program.

At first I wanted to be sure, I ran gdb with quotes around your args, it is removed at launch.

This works too, but optional:

```
gdb --args executablename "--arg1" "--arg2" "--arg3"
```

This doesn't work :

```
gdb --args executablename "--arg1" "--arg2" "--arg3" -tui
```

In that case, `-tui` is used as my program parameter not as gdb one.

Answer (score 7):

Much too late, but here is a method that works during `gdb` session.

> `gdb <executable>`

then

> `(gdb) apropos argument`

This will return lots of matches, the useful one is `set args`.

```
set args -- Set argument list to give program being debugged when it is started.
```

> `set args arg1 arg2 ...`

then

> `r`

This will run the program, passing to main(argc, argv) the arguments and the argument count.

Answer (score 6):

If the `--args` parameter is not working on your machine (i.e. on Solaris 8), you may start gdb like

```
gdb -ex "set args <arg 1> <arg 2> ... <arg n>"
```

And you can combine this with inputting a file to stdin and "running immediatelly":

```
gdb -ex "set args <arg 1> <arg 2> ... <arg n> < <input file>" -ex "r"
```

Answer (score 4):

gdb has `--init-command <somefile>` where somefile has a list of gdb commands to run, I use this to have `//GDB` comments in my code, then `

```
echo "file ./a.out" > run
grep -nrIH "//GDB"|
    sed "s/\(^[^:]\+:[^:]\+\):.*$/\1/g" |
    awk '{print "b" " " $1}'|
    grep -v $(echo $0|sed "s/.*\///g") >> run
gdb --init-command ./run -ex=r
```

as a script, which puts the command to load the debug symbols, and then generates a list of break commands to put a break point for each `//GDB` comment, and starts it running

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass arguments from file,
e.g. scanf from a file as input

try this

```
(gdb) run < the_file_contains_data
```