# set environment variable in GDB from output of command

Tags: linux, command-line, gdb, environment-variables, command-substitution

I am trying to exploit a buffer overflow in a challenge, the buffer gets it's value from an environment variable.
In GDB I know that you can set environment variables using the command:

```
set environment username = test
```

However I need to pass the username variable special characters, so I need to do something like:

```
set environment username= $(echo -e '\xff\x4c......')
```

But that command doesn't get executed and the username variable contains literally what I wrote down, does anybody know a trick to pass special characters to an environment variable?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55593045/94687

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you really need to do it *from GDB*, here is one example:

**hello.c**

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("argv[1]=%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("VAR=%s\n", getenv("VAR"));
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ gcc -g -o hello hello.c
$ gdb ./hello
...
(gdb) set exec-wrapper bash -c 'exec env VAR="`echo myEnv`" "$@"' --
(gdb) r myArg
...
argv[1]=myArg
VAR=myEnv
```

Change `VAR` and `echo myEnv` to a variable and command you need.

---

But note that setting `VAR` from shell before starting GDB also works:

```
$ VAR=`echo Hey there` gdb ./hello
...
(gdb) r myArg
...
argv[1]=myArg
VAR=Hey there
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting gdb from shell command-line, you can specify which program to run, [with which arguments (with `--args`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776339/94687), and even modify the environment of the program with the help of `env`!

I just did it successfully like this:

```sh
gdb --ex=run --args env LD_BIND=now LD_DEBUG=libs \
apt-get install --yes $(cat pkgs-to-install-to-crash-apt)
```

`--ex=run` is to ask gdb to run it immediately.