# How to set environment variable within GDB using shell command?

Tags: linux, command-line, gdb, environment-variables, command-substitution

I want to run `gdb` with only a single variable `MyVar` in its environment.

However, the variable's contents are rather complex, containing non-printable ASCII, and so is best set using e.g. `MyVar=$(python -c 'print("\xff...")')`.

I'm left with two options:

1. Set the `MyVar` in `bash` before running `gdb`. Then inside `gdb`, remove all other environment variables individually using `unset environment NAME` (**very tedious!**).
2. Clear all environment variables using `unset environment`. Then inside `gdb`, set `MyVar` using a shell command (as above) (**how?)**

Any ideas?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34726206/94687

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set environment variable in GDB from output of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726206/set-environment-variable-in-gdb-from-output-of-command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 2 is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885923/redirecting-storing-output-of-shell-into-gdb-variable).

```
(gdb) unset environment
(gdb) python gdb.execute("set environment Myvar=\xff")
(gdb) show environment 
Myvar=ÿ
```

Option 1 can be done with [`env(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html).

```
$ env -i MyVar=$(python -c 'print("xyz")') gdb
(gdb) show environment
MyVar=xyz
LINES=35
COLUMNS=80
```

Then you just have to clear LINES and COLUMNS.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what LINES and COLUMNS mean? They are environment variables set by GDB I suppose.

Comment: Yes, they are the lines and columns of the terminal, and GDB sets them internally. See [here](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=readline/terminal.c;h=8094186bba21a91ed02b962988b90769cb323312;hb=HEAD#l230) and [here](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=readline/shell.c;h=ac0fb3604b8a9d6abcfbfcea6ee79e5f3cad549e;hb=HEAD#l124).

Comment: it's wierd, I cannot get option 2 to work. After having executed the Python command, I check `show environment` and no environment variables there. The option 1 is also wierd. The stack is different from running `env -i MyVar="..." prog` with ASLR disabled - any ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example for option 2. I actually like it better than option 1 now! As for ASLR, that wasn't in your original question but if I disable it with `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` then I get the same output from this program every time: 
`#include <stdio.h>`
`void foo() { int x = 0; printf("&x = %p\n", &x); }`
`int main() { foo(); return 0; }`

Comment: Thanks again. Does all newer versions of GDB come with Python support or is it something that I need to install through addons?

Comment: It looks like version 7 and up.

Comment: If you need to run a program with a custom environment, it'd be better not run the whole gdb under `env`, but just the program, with `gdb --args env ...`, as demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571461/94687

Answer (score 9):

When starting gdb from shell command-line, you can specify which program to run, [with which arguments (with `--args`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776339/94687), and even modify the environment of the program with the help of `env`!

I just did it successfully like this:

```bash
gdb --ex=run --args env LD_BIND_NOW=1 LD_DEBUG=libs \
apt-get install --yes $(cat pkgs-to-install-to-crash-apt)
```

`--ex=run` is to ask gdb to run it immediately.

In your case, you would do `env -i`.

It differs from the suggested `env -i VAR=... gdb program` in that only your examined program is under the special environment, but not gdb.

Comment: Even though my answer was accepted, I like this one better since it does not affect gdb itself.

Comment: One thing to take into account with that: if you want to break at the beginning of your main entry point, then you have to use something else than the `start` command, otherwise, you stop in `env`'s entry point, before it replaces the program with some `exec*()`.