# Debugging Gtk-CRITICAL

Tags: gdb, gtk

When running my program, I am getting `Gtk-CRITICAL` error on the Terminal, which I'd like to fix.

I found [this link](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2005-May/msg00024.html) through Google, but turns out there is no such option in gdb:

```
igor@IgorReinCloud ~/dbhandler/Debug/dbhandler $ gdb --g-fatal-warnings dbhandler
gdb: unrecognized option '--g-fatal-warnings'
Use `gdb --help' for a complete list of options.
```

I also tried to set a breakpoint on the g_log() function, but the execution didn't stop there.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals`, so that the application execution breaks at the first location where a critical is emitted.

To run inside gdb, run `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals gdb my-app`, and as usual, do `run` inside gdb to run your application.

You may also set the `G_DEBUG` environment variable with `export` (if in `bash`). Thus you could do `export G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals`, and then run your app as `gdb my-app`, which will have the same effect.

See https://docs.gtk.org/glib/running.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

Looks like that after reading the link, you were confused that gdb should have `--g-fatal-warnings` option for debugging Gtk applications. This is not the case because gdb is not Gtk application, but your program is. So you should run your program with `--g-fatal-warnings` option inside gdb like this:

```
gdb --args dbhandler --g-fatal-warnings
```

See also related question [How do I run a program with commandline args using gdb within a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121094/72178).