# How to pass parameters to GDB script?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a GDB script which I pass to GDB:

```
gdb -x my_script.gdb
```

Inside `my_script.gdb` I have a variable, say `foo`, which I use as a parameter. Right now, I manually change `foo` inside the script whenever I want to try a different value for `foo`.

What I would like to do, is pass a command-line parameter when launching GDB with the command above, so that `foo` takes the value of that parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121094/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-commandline-arguments-using-gdb-within-a-bash-script

Comment: But this is for passing arguments to the program, isn't it? I want to pass a parameter to the script itself

Comment: Perhaps this is the documentation you are looking for: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/objfile_002dgdbdotext-file.html#objfile_002dgdbdotext-file It seems that you can pass a Python file to `gdb` in which case you can definitely have arguments if the `gdb` script doesn't let you. Alternatively, you can write a Bash script that outputs line-separated commands and you can pipe that to `gdb`.

Answer (score 6):

You can emulate this behavior with [User-defined Commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html). You can define some function in `my_script.gdb` script and call it with arguments from command line:

```
$ cat my_script.gdb
define func
   print $arg0
end
$ gdb -q -x my_script.gdb -ex "func 123"
$1 = 123
(gdb)
```