# "\\.\\PhysicalDrive1" is not a core dump: file format not recognized

Tags: c, windows, winapi, fileapi

I have been working on a fantasy console type project. I decided to zero a flash drive I had laying around and use it as the ROM input to the fantasy console. While trying to write code to read bytes directly from the drive (rather than from a file on the drive) I have found a peculiar bug.

Trying to open the drive via `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` with the file path `\\.\\PhysicalDrive1` results in the error "`"\\.\\PhysicalDrive1" is not a core dump: file format not recognized`"

I have tried changing input options and I have tried alternate file paths, but anything I try results in the drive either not being found or the error shown above. Information on this issue is very scarse from my research, and what little info I have found is specific to Linux, and involves very different situations.

Here is my code (not the cleanest but it *should* work):

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Opening %s\n", argv[1]);

    HANDLE romf = CreateFile((LPCSTR)argv[1], 
                                GENERIC_READ,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ, 
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    
    if (romf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("File %s not found\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t rom[4] = { 0 };
    LPDWORD read = 0;

    int res = ReadFile(romf, rom, 4, read, NULL);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("Error reading file (%d)\n", argv[1], GetLastError());
        
        CloseHandle(romf);
        return -1;
    }
    
    printf("Read $%x bytes\n", read);

    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", rom[0], rom[1], rom[2], rom[3]);

    CloseHandle(romf);

    return 0;
}
```

I have used `gdb` to debug the code and to get the error message.

Comment: `\\.\\PhysicalDrive1` in any case is is wrong. need use `\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive1` if you want open `PhysicalDrive1`

Comment: `(LPCSTR)argv[1]` is a bug. If you need to cast, you're doing it wrong. Either call `CreateFileA`, or - preferably - use `CreateFileW` and supply a wide character string. The easiest way is to define a [`wmain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain) entry point. If you cannot do that you can call [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) passing the return value of [`GetCommandLineW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code you have shown produces the error message that you have claimed. That error message is a debugger message, not a compiler error, or a runtime system error. This issue has nothing to do with the code you have shown, and everything to do with how you are using the debugger.

Per the [gdb documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html):

> You can also start with both an executable program and a core file specified:
>
> `gdb program core`

In comments, you state that you are running `gdb ./bin/clt \\.\\PhysicalDrive1`, which means you are calling gdb with `\\.\\PhysicalDrive1` in the `core` parameter, but that path does not point to a valid core dump file, hence the error.  You are expecting gdb to pass `\\.\\PhysicalDrive1` as a command-line parameter to your program, but that is not what it is actually doing. To do that, use the `--args` parameter (see [How do I run a program with commandline arguments using GDB within a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121094/)), eg:

`gdb --args ./bin/clt \\.\PhysicalDrive1`

---

That said, there are a number of bugs in your code.

- you are not checking if `argc > 1` is true before accessing `argv[1]`.
- the `LPCSTR` cast in the `lpFileName` parameter of `CreateFile()` is not needed and should be removed. `argv[1]` is a `char*` and you are casting it to `const char*` (which `CreateFile()` wants, if you are compiling a MBCS build and not a UNICODE build). The compiler can do that cast implicitly for you.
- you are passing a `NULL` pointer to the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter of `ReadFile()`. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile):

  > [out, optional] lpNumberOfBytesRead
  >
  > A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous hFile parameter. ReadFile sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking. Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
  >
  > This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

  You are not performing an *asynchronous* read, so you must provide a pointer to an actual `DWORD` variable instead:

  ```
  DWORD read = 0;

  int res = ReadFile(romf, rom, 4, &read, NULL);
  ```
- your error message when `ReadFile()` fails is being formatted incorrectly. You forgot to include a `%s` placeholder for `argv[1]`, so you are passing `argv[1]` (a `char*`) to the `%d` placeholder, which expects an `int`, and you are not passing the value of `GetLastError()` to any placeholder at all. You need to fix your format string, eg:

  ```
  printf("Error reading file %s (%d)\n", argv[1], GetLastError());
  ```

Comment: I stated in my post that I used GDB to get the error message

Comment: &read instead of read raises an error ` note: expected 'LPDWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int *'} but argument is of type 'DWORD **' {aka 'long unsigned int **'}`

Comment: and `printf("Error reading file %s (%d)\n", argv[1], GetLastError());` literally never happens in the code I posted

Comment: @TobiNoara "*&read instead of read raises an error*" - you didn't change the *type* of `read` from `LPDWORD` to `DWORD`, like I showed.

Comment: "*and `"Error reading file %s (%d)\n"` literally never happens in the code I posted*". - I know, and that is a bug. Your format string is wrong, for the reasons I stated. The string I proposed is the fix.

Comment: Well I did that and it compiles without error, but the ACTUAL issue still persists

Comment: Also I don't need to restate what file it's reading

Comment: @TobiNoara the core dump issue you are asking about has NOTHING to do with the code you showed, and EVERYTHING to do with how you are using the debugger, which you did not explain.

Comment: `gcc -g ./src./clt/main.c -o ./bin/clt.exe; gdb ./bin/clt \\.\\PhysicalDrive1`

Comment: @TobiNoara I have updated my answer to explain what is happening