# How to use GDB to debug code with command line arguments

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, fortran, gdb

When I do a crystal plasticity simulation use damask, I modify the constitutive code file, but I do not know how to debug it.

I run the code:

```
DAMASK_grid --load tensionX.yaml --geom 1011231113_small_geo.vti
```

When I run it in terminal, it show that [the error when run my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIwvw.png)

```
Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
```

When I want to use gdb to debug, I can not use

```
gdb DAMASK_grid --load tensionX.yaml --geom 1011231113_small_geo.vti
```

to debug it. I get

```
gdb: unrecognized option '--load' Use `gdb --help' for a complete list of options.
```

How can I find what happens in my code? How can I find out which line of my code causes the error?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. You do not show how you compile the code but that is very important. When debugging always use error checking flags in your compiler. E.g.`gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all` and consider also `-Wall`. Otjer compilers have similar flags.

Comment: "it can not use `gdb ...`"  What does it mean it cannot? What **exactly** happens? Any error message? See [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава the key code i compile it is 'cmake -S damask-3.0.0-alpha7 -B build-grid -DDAMASK_SOLVER=grid
sudo cmake --build build-grid --target install
cmake -S damask-3.0.0-alpha7 -B build-mesh -DDAMASK_SOLVER=mesh
sudo cmake --build build-mesh --target install'

Comment: That does not help much because we can't see the actual compiler commands. And what kind of error are you getting when trying gdb?

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава actually, i don't know how to trying gdb. because i run my simulation by the code 'DAMASK_grid --load tensionX.yaml --geom 1011231113_small_geo.vti' in ubuntu terminal dicrectly.

Comment: So try `gdb DAMASK_grid --load tensionX.yaml --geom 1011231113_small_geo.vti` in ubuntu terminal directly.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава
gdb DAMASK_grid --load tensionX.yaml --geom 1011231113_small_geo.vti
gdb: unrecognized option '--load'
Use `gdb --help' for a complete list of options.

Comment: Show it in the question by doing an [edit]. Always show any error messages you get. I really suggest to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121094/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-commandline-arguments-using-gdb-within-a-bash-script

Comment: Please use tags only if they affect the question you're asking. I don't see how `simulation` would influence your ability to run `gdb`.

Comment: Finally, please be aware that you may need to tweak the compiler options used by cmake to get the debugging symbols to make the output of `gdb` useful. Please refer to my first comment to a recommended set of options for gfortran.