# GDB input files and such

Tags: c, file, gdb

I'm trying to debug a program however I need a txt file for input. I am unsure as how I gte the text file to fun with the program. I compiled as
       
      gcc -g filename.c filename1.c
       
      a < text.txt

and also doing some while already in the debugger. The program keeps exiting because the file is NULL. How do I get the txt file to be inputted into the program?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521015/passing-arguments-to-program-run-through-gdb

Comment: Okay, I tried r < textfile.txt and it says, "Starting program... [New Thread...] <br> [New Thread...] <br> [Inferior 1 (process 3516) exited with code 01]" Is this a problem with input or a problem with my program?

Comment: does the program run when you run it not under `gdb`?

Comment: Yes, only half of it works, but it runs.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `main`, then run the program.

Comment: @n.m. I can't run it without the input file. It exits at the file is NULL.

Comment: "[Inferior 1 (process 3516) exited with code 01]" is *normal* exit if the code return 1 or some other function return 1. Say: `(gdb)b main` `(gdb) r < textfile.txt`

Comment: @Rune: slightly simpler variant: `(gdb) start < textfile.txt` - no need to set a breakpoint on `main()` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

Or, are you trying to open "textfile.txt" with `fopen` inside your program?

- [Standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)
- [Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

---

Only to give an example / be clear:

First of; that is a bad compile line, even worse when you have problems, but then again you might simplified it for us.

Use something like:

```
 $ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ggdb -o myprog mycode.c
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    while((i = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(i);
    return 1; /* Normally you would use 0, 1 indicate some error. */
}
```

In terminal:

```
$ gdb ./my_prog
(gdb) r < textfile.txt
Starting program: /home/xm/devel/ext/so/my_prog < textfile.txt
Text text text
Text text text
Text text text
Text text text

[Inferior 1 (process 17678) exited with code 01]
(gdb) q
```

---

Threads (bad code but ...):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *say_hello(void *threadid)
{
    printf("Helllu!\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *read_stdin(void *threadid)
{
    int i;

    while((i = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(i);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t threads[2];
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, read_stdin, (void*)0);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, say_hello,  (void*)1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

In terminal:

```
$ gdb ./my_prog
(gdb) r < textfile.txt
Starting program: /home/xm/devel/ext/so/my_prog < textfile.txt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0xb7fd9b70 (LWP 17843)]
Text text text
Text text text
Text text text
Text text text

[New Thread 0xb77d8b70 (LWP 17844)]
Helllu!
[Thread 0xb77d8b70 (LWP 17844) exited]
[Thread 0xb7fd9b70 (LWP 17843) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 17840) exited normally]
```