# Debug argument based C program with gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have c++ program which I run by passing string with it.

```
g++ -o a main.cpp -lpthread
```

and execute it with `./a "Good nice"`

But how I debug it with gdb?
main.cpp calling functions from other files which are included in it.

```
gdb ./a "Good nice"
```

takes "--" as files and says no such file!

I want to debug line by line!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to program run through gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521015/passing-arguments-to-program-run-through-gdb)

Comment: Also compile your program with `-g` otherwise this is all for nothing

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--args` option of gdb:

```
gdb --args ./a "Good nice"
```

Also add the `-g` option to your compiler call, because otherwise gdb won't be able to connect your executable with your source code:

```
g++ -g -o a main.cpp -lpthread
```

Comment: he also has to compile with `-g`

Comment: @aaronman yes, to be able to use the debugger at all. But wasn't this question about the program arguments problem?

Comment: If he shows you how he's compiling it and you know it's wrong and you don't tell him, is your answer useful?

Comment: If we are at it, you should also add -Wall... ;-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp Cheers :D but I think that would really start going off topic. I can upvote your comment, though.

Comment: first `g++ -g -o b main.cpp foo.cpp` then `gdb --args ./b "good nice"
`. Then `s` for line by line execution gives `the program is not being run`

Comment: Well, in any case you need to say `run` to gdb before trying to step through a program. Before that, gdb does not start a process which you could debug. I know, it is awkward that gdb doesn't do this automatically when it starts, but that's the way it is. Likely, you'll want to set a breakpoint (`break`) after saying `run`, so that you don't have to step through your entire program to reach the interesting point, but that is optional, `run` breaks at the start of `main()`. Correct sequence: `g++ -g ...`, `gdb --args ...`, `run`, [`break ...`], all the other commands you use to debug your code.

Answer (score 5):

Use gdb without argument

```
gdb ./a
```

Then in gdb, before running the program

```
set args "Good nice"
```

And you can see what arguments you set, use

```
show args
```

See [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_18.html) for detail.

Comment: A side note: If in case you have doubts in middle what args you set, use `show args`

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Exactly, I'm adding that to the answer.

Comment: after above procedure when I press `s` to start line by line debug it gives ` the program is not being run `

Comment: you need to run it by typing 'run'.

Answer (score 3):

*gdb ./prog* -> *set args* `string` -> *run*.

Comment: This will execute entire program and gives output. I want line by line debug!

Answer (score 3):

Anther choice is provide argument after `run`

```
$gdb ./a
 run "Good nice"
```