# Using gdb To run executable with a text file as input provided as parameters

Tags: c++, debugging, powershell, compilation, gdb

1. I want to achieve this behavior:

   `Executable.exe<inputfile.txt`

   using Command Prompt it works but fails in Windows PowerShell, why?
   How to achieve this behavior in PowerShell?
2. In PowerShell I want to use **`gdb`** to debug the `executable.exe` (built usign **-g** arguments), but with `inputfile.txt`as arguments to executable. How to achieve both of these?

Comment: For question 1, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763086/why-is-input-redirect-not-implemented-in-powershell . `Get-Content inputfile.txt | Executable.exe`

Comment: For questino 2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521015/passing-arguments-to-program-run-through-gdb