# passing the output of one .py script to another in GDB

Tags: python, gdb

How to pass the output of one .py script which I executed in GDB using below command:

```
(gdb)source myfilename.py
```

to another .py script myfilename2.py

E.g: On running myfile myfilename.py in GDB I get the below results

```
(gdb)source myfilename.py
(gdb)print $function("input")
(gdb)$1 = someoutput`
```

If I want to pass $1 as input to another .py script how do I do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can run other python programs output to another in gdb, but of course you can pass output of a command like this.

```
   (gdb) run "`python -c 'print "\xff\xff\xff\xff"'`"
```

May be you can try passing the second .py file instead of the command for its output to be passed into first .py.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use contents of GDB variable $1 for your program input, since program launch is performed by shell, not by gdb.

You can store your script output in file, launch gdb for your executable and use command

```
(gdb)run <outputfile
```

Or use a named pipe, as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456253/gdb-debugging-with-pipe).