# gdb does not stop when piping the command

Tags: c, gdb

When running the usual way, `gdb` stops as expected:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
Starting program ...
Breakpoint 1, main ...
```

when running while piping, `gdb` never stops:

```
(gdb) run | cat
Starting program: /home/sds/z | cat
...
During startup program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

**How do I debug program behavior when piping?**

my setup:

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Amazon Linux (7.6.1-64.33.amzn1)
$ uname -a
Linux datasci-1 4.4.19-29.55.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 29 23:29:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
```

same problem on the most recent fully updated ubuntu (16.10).

Comment: It seems piping output like that may not work right with gdb... what about redirecting with `>` to a fifo instead?

Comment: thanks, fifo work, but it still seems wrong for gdb to behave this way. is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

While input and output redirection work, you cannot use pipes to pass the output of the program you are debugging to another program; if you attempt this, GDB is likely to wind up debugging the wrong program.

https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.html

Comment: could you please substantiate the claim that "GDB is likely to wind up debugging the wrong program"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34621512/850781):

```
(gdb) run > >(cat)
```

See [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).