# How to use gdb with pipes and stdin

Tags: bash, debugging, gdb, pipe, stdin

Hi, i'm trying to debug a program that I run with a command

```
cat 1.txt - | ./game
```

And I'm not sure how to start `gdb` with that command. I've seen answers to how to pipe to `gdb`, but it doesn't seem to work when I first want to pipe the file content but then use standard input (this is what the dash stands for). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

> `cat 1.txt - | ./game`

This `cat` is pointless, you could just as easily do this: `./game < 1.txt`.

Which can also be used to run the `game` under GDB:

```
gdb ./game
(gdb) run < 1.txt
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456358/50617).

Comment: The `cat` wasn't pointless. Without the dash the program looped printing the message and waiting for input, because the code looked something like this: `while (1) { printf("message"); if (scanf("%d", &var) > 0 && var >= 0 ) { break; } getchar();}`

Comment: Though the `cat` is _usually_ pointless in such cases, I'm dealing right now with a program, which takes a different code-path depending on whether the input can be `mmap()`ed or not... And it _can_ be, if you simply supply the input file as the `stdin` redirection -- but not, when it comes as output from some other program...