# How to use gdb with input redirection?

Tags: gdb, io

In the Terminal, I have:

```
myapp < myfileinput
```

But if I want to use gdb,

```
gdb myapp < myfileinput
```

It didn't run correctly.

How to use `gdb` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load program reading stdin and taking parameters in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
~$ gdb <executable>

GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/abhishek/maxtest...done.

(gdb) run < input.txt
```

This is doing the trick for me. Wondering if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: This [doesn’t work on cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00304.html)

Comment: Also works with `start < inputfile` if you want to start debugging at the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: For multiple inputs, U can separate the inputs with new line in the input.txt.

Answer (score 13):

Try running your application from within gdb?

```
(gdb) file /usr/bin/head
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/head...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run -2 < /etc/passwd
Starting program: /usr/bin/head -2 < /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

EDIT: Alternatively:

```
gdb -q -ex 'set args -2 < /etc/passwd' /usr/bin/head
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/head...done.

(gdb) run
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh

Program exited normally.
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: Sorry, but why the `-2`? Why not just `gdb -ex 'set args < file' ./binary` ?

Comment: Oh! Ok! You mean `head -2`, the two first lines of a file. Just another arg. My bad. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
(gdb) run < input.txt
```

Comment: This [doesn’t work on cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00304.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative seems to be:

```
$ gdb /usr/bin/head
(gdb) set args `cat /etc/passwd`
(gdb) run
```