# GDB stuck in infinite loop when debugging progam with standard input

Tags: c++, c, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm using GDB to do some reverse engineering of a basic C program. The program does not accept command line input. It does accept input from standard in during run time. I'm trying to script the standard in by doing

```
run < temp
```

Where temp is a file containing something like

```
1
0
AAAAAAAAA
AAAAA
0
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, GDB appears to loop infinitely over this programs input.

I tried to make this file using python

```
python -c 'print "AAAAA"' > temp
```

And with the solution presented here: [How to debug a program that takes user input from stdin with GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104206/gdb-user-input-from-stdin)

But no luck.  When I just step through the program with GDB, I can pass input via standard in and that work's just fine.

I'm a bit stumped...

Comment: Are you using Cygwin? There's a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758175/how-to-use-gdb-with-input-redirection) that says this doesn't work there.

Comment: See https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00308.html

Comment: @Barmar: I'm not using Cygwin.... but that error does sound very similar. I'm going to try on a different computer later and provide an update. Hmm...

How did you find that? My google-fu is apparently weak.

Comment: I googled "gdb redirect program input" and it found that question.

Comment: Nope. Tried on a new computer with a fresh OS install. No luck.

Comment: What operating system? Unix or Windows?

Comment: Unix. One time with a RHEL install and the other time with Kali.

Comment: Are you sure the program is reading from stdin, not /dev/tty? If you run it outside `gdb`, can you redirect its input to a file?