# Simulating echo input with GDB

Tags: stream, terminal, gdb, stdin

So I am trying to debug a program which requires the user to input some text through the terminal:

```
$ echo 'here is the text' | ./program
```

How do I simulate that input in GDB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load program reading stdin and taking parameters in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the program with input redirected:

```
echo 'here is the text' > intput.txt
gdb ./program
(gdb) run < intput.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that could be the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can do using `--args` option giving program executable followed by arguments as below,

```
 % gdb --args ./program arg1 arg2
```

Comment: So I replace --args with 'here is the text'? Or where does the text go?

Comment: @Foxxy - arguments should go after your program i.e arg1 and if multiple arguments followed by.

Comment: But I'm not talking about arguments here, I'm talking about the STDIN. Hence the 'here is the text' part of the prompt.