# how to gdb a program containing parameters

Tags: c, gdb

often i see some gdb guide using examples without parameters. But in parctice, i need to gdb debug a programe with parameters.

this program is run as "./voronoi -t outputfile", -t is programme voronoi itself parameter,  is input, and outputfile is outputfile.  but when i using "gdb ./voronoi -t outputfile", it will tell me some error, but when using no gdb debug, run "./voronoi -t outputfile" is OK.

How make it both can gdb debugging and aslo with parameters? How to set the parameters?

Comment: plz read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455544/how-to-load-program-reading-stdin-and-taking-parameters-in-gdb?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `run` and `start` commands of gdb—you can pass them the commandline parameters just like you are used to at the shell prompt:

```
% gdb my_program
[...]
start par1 par2 par3 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

$ gdb program

break linenumber|functionName

run [parameters]

Answer (score 0):

if your system is windows,you can do this:
1.gdb your_program
2.set args para1 para2 para3...