# How to input unprintable ascii value in gdb when debugging a interacting program？

Tags: gdb

Since the value I am gonna input is unpredictable befor the program runs. So is there any way to input like "\x01\x02" in gdb？
The program I am debugging is a c program and the function in the program which needs an input is gets().
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you input these values when run without gdb?

Comment: Without gdb, stdin redirection can be used to send unprintable value for simple. And python script can be used too.

Comment: You can [redirect stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455588/1983398) with gdb as well.

Comment: Do you need to start the program and run it for a bit before you can determine what input to send to it?

Answer (score 0):

> the value I am gonna input is unpredictable befor the program runs

Assuming that you mean: "the value that needs to be read can only be determined while debugging the program with GDB", use [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) as input (and [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455588/50617) GDB I/O redirection).